# How to set cookies when user votes

Tags: php, cookies

i've read the cookies tutorial on w3schools BUT i do not fully understand it so i've come to ask this question over here to know more about it. Let's say we have two buttons, an UP button and a DOWN button, when the user clicks on either one of the buttons (and the cookie will be set here), both the buttons will be unclickable until that user clears his/her cookies. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Which part you did not understand? What have you tried? If that tutorial didn't help, did you try reading some other tutorial?

Comment: @juhanna no i haven't read tutorials that could help. Linking to some would be helpful :) THanks!

Comment: Be careful when using w3schools, despite it's google ranking it's not always the best advice. http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control the *cookies* as you control the $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET and $_SESSION arrays using **$_COOKIES**.

You can set teh cookie with the function:

```
setcookie("CookieName", $value, time()+3600, $path, $domain);
```

And you can clear or get the cookie value acessing the $_COOKIE array:

```
echo $_COOKIE["CookieName"];
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["CookieName"];
print_r($_COOKIE);
unset($_COOKIE["CookieName"]);
```

Or use the function above:

```
setcookie("CookieName", '');
```

After that you can make something like that in the page:

**OffButton**

```
if($_COOKIE["CookieName"]!=1){
       echo "disabled";
    }
```

**OnButton**

```
 if($_REQUEST["buttonname"]==1){
       echo "enabled";
    }
```